# Swift generic cast to Protocol fails with swift_dynamicCastUnknownClass

Tags: swift, generics

The following example is taken from Apple Swift Reference guide. I only added the getHasAreaInstances() and getGenericHasAreaInstances()

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol HasArea {
  var area: Double { get }
}

@objc protocol HasExtendedArea: HasArea {
  var extendedArea: Double { get }
}

class Circle: HasArea {
  let pi = 3.1415927
  var radius: Double
  var area: Double { return pi * radius * radius }
  init(radius: Double) { self.radius = radius }
}
class Country: HasArea {
  var area: Double
  init(area: Double) { self.area = area }
}

class Continent: HasExtendedArea {
  var area: Double { return 300 }
  var extendedArea: Double { return 3000 }
}

let objects: [HasArea] = [
  Circle(radius: 2.0),
  Country(area: 243_610),
  Continent()
]

for object in objects {
  if let objectWithArea = object as? HasExtendedArea {
    println("Extended Area is \(objectWithArea.area)")
  } else {
    println("Area is not extended")
  }
}
// Extended Area is 300.0
// Area is not extended
// Area is not extended
```

The method below returns the correct array:

```
func getHasExtendedAreaInstances() -> [HasExtendedArea] {
  var haveArea: [HasExtendedArea] = []

  for object in objects {
    if let objectWithArea = object as? HasExtendedArea {
      haveArea.append(objectWithArea)
    }
  }

  return haveArea
}

let areas = getHasExtendedAreaInstances()
//[Continent]
```

The method below returns the correct array:

```
func getGenericHasExtendedAreaInstances<T>() -> [T] {
  var haveArea: [T] = []

  for object in objects {
    if let objectWithArea = object as? T {
      haveArea.append(objectWithArea)
    }
  }

  return haveArea
}

let areasGeneric: [HasExtendedArea] = getGenericHasExtendedAreaInstances()
//[Continent]
```

However, as soon as a constraint is imposed on the generic type, it no longer works

```
func getGenericConstraintHasExtendedAreaInstances<T: HasArea>() -> [T] {
  var haveArea: [T] = []

  for object in objects {
    if let objectWithArea = object as? T {
// the line above fails with swift_dynamicCastUnknownClass
      haveArea.append(objectWithArea)
    }
  }

  return haveArea
}

let areasGenericConstraint: [HasExtendedArea] = getGenericConstraintHasExtendedAreaInstances()
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this generic `func getGenericHasAreaInstances<T: HasArea>() -> [T]`? What is supposed to resolve that? In what sense does that need to be a generic? What is that generic function intended to do that would be in any way different than the original nongeneric version of the function?

Comment: @matt good question, I was thinking that (but not confident about it) in this instance the generic function returns an array of any object type that conforms to the HasArea protocol. In the non generic function it also returns an array of any object that conforms to the protocol right? so in a way the non generic function has generic facets?

Comment: The restriction `<T: HasArea>` of the type placeholder makes no sense. If you remove that: `func getGenericHasAreaInstances<T>() -> [T]` then it works.

Comment: @MartinR Why do you say it makes no sense, isn't it the same as <T where T:HasArea> - i.e. declaring the type using this generic function much conform to the HasArea protocol? -

Comment: I updated the example to make some more sense.. In my implementation I have a superclass that has an array of HasArea protocols and I need to access only a subset of these protocols in my subclasses (based on the inherited protocol).. But they will all be of type HasArea.. So, why wouldn't I be allowed to constrain the generic?

Comment: I did express myself badly, and I am also still guessing about the real problem. But in your (original) code this restriction is not needed, and without it the program runs as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Swift 1.2, tested on Xcode 6.3 Beta 3

You can specify the type constraint without swift compiler failing on you

Answer (score 2):

Your generic function makes no sense. What would resolve it? What would satisfy it? Make a simpler example with the same basic declaration structure: it's an impossible function. For example, start with this nongeneric function:

```
class Thing : Printable {
    var description : String {return "thing"}
}
func g() -> [Thing] {
    return [Thing()]
}
let result : [Thing] = g()
```

Now modify `g` to be generic, exactly parallel to your function:

```
class Thing : Printable {
    var description : String {return "thing"}
}
func g<T:Printable>() -> [T] {
    return [Thing()]
}
let result : [Thing] = g()
```

It doesn't compile - because it makes no sense.

Comment: Actually you would need to have `let result : [Printable] = g()` which would yield `error: generic parameter 'T' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'Printable'`

Comment: @Ciprian Very true. My point is that you can't munge my example to make it compile in any way shape or form. The generic makes no sense no matter what you do; this has nothing to do with the Apple example code you started with. It's just a matter of understanding generics. Your whole discussion starting with Apple's example is a red herring - this is a simple matter of how generic functions work.

Comment: @Ciprian You might want to read my new Swift tutorial, where I explain generics: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics I'm not saying my explanation is the be-all and end-all (generics have a lot of tricky corners) but I do think I explain them a lot better than Apple does.